# Find the columns with True value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with columns that there is only a True in a row (like the df below). How may I form a column with the column index that has True for that row? In real life the matrix is big, so I avoid using for loop and apply.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True,False,False],
                   [True,False,False],
                   [False,True,False],
                   [False,False,True],
                   [True,False,False],
                   ])
```

The answer shall be sth like:

```
df['TrueColIndex'] = [0,0,1,2,1]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `idxmax`

```
df.idxmax(1)
Out[444]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    0
dtype: int64
```